# Composer.json vendor folder on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I am migrating from shared web hosting to Heroku and can't figure out how to user Composer properly.

I have my app pointing to `public_html` folder, with the `composer.json` file in the root folder above this. This would generate a `vendor` folder in the root folder, which (for reasons I don't understand) I was unable to access when I tried including the autoload.php file in my code (e.g. `require_once('../vendor/autoload.php')`).

My solution to this was to move `composer.json` into `public_html`, but that caused no end of problems with Heroku not finding it, so I moved it back. I then changed the vendor directory in `composer.json` to point to `public_html/vendor`.

This had the desired effect, except now my app won't run because it can't find PHP, presumably something to do with the new location of vendor.

Is there a way to either:

1. Configure composer.json to have Heroku put everything except PHP in `public_html/vendor`, and put PHP into a root `vendor` directory, or
2. Access files above `public_html` from within my code to allow me to include `autoload.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out it was a relatively simple fix that I just figured out myself. I'll post it here in case anybody else happens to make the same mistake.

If you change `vendor-dir` in `composer.json`, you also need to change the `Procfile` from

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public_html/`

to

`web: public_html/vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public_html/`